# SQLite support on Windows Phone

Tags: codenameone

I'm currently porting an Android app to codename one. For the new app it is a requirement to work on iOS, Android and Windows Phone. In the description of the default codename one [Database](http://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/db/Database.html) class it says that Windows Phone is not supported and should only used for "very large data handling". Instead the more portable Storage class should be used for small storage.

The native App currently uses several SQLite tables with rather difficult queries. I wouldn't call the amount of data very large, but definitely more than "small".

In [The Road Ahead](http://www.codenameone.com/blog/the-road-ahead-2015-in-review-survey-results.html) post it said that you will work on better Windows Phone support and also that something better for database storage is needed. Is there anything new planned for this or do I have no other choice than porting it somehow to Storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As part of the Windows VM rewrite we will need some form of database whether it will be the builtin sqlite or some other solution for SQL. Unfortunately we are still not at that stage in terms of the implementation so its pretty hard to tell when this will launch.

So generally there should be an SQL solution for Windows coming at some point but it's really hard to tell when that point in time will be. Ideally we want it ASAP but there are physical time/resource constraints involved.